# Opencart set Store preferences

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

In Opencart we have the following type of products.

Printed Books (hard copies) which will be shipped to customer.

For the same we have Digital Downloads.

We want an option set at the store level whether user wants to see Downloads or Printed Copies.

When the user chooses downloads option, it should display only downloadable products in all the categories.

When user chooses Printed Copies, it should display only printed products in each of the categories.

Any suggestions to achieve this functionality are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: my suggestion would be to first try and write some code.  then you can come here for help with it when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

> **"Any suggestions to achieve this functionality"**

From my point of view (which may not be optimal) we need:

- **Permanent storage for the user preference *[5 % done]***
  add a column to the table `<DB_PREFIX>customer` with a type of `INT` and a value of `0` if the user is interested in all products, `1` for digital downloads and so on..., if there is a possibility that you will add new preferences later, then it's better to store a serialized version of all the user preferences in a column of type `TEXT`
- **A way to retrieve user preference *[25 % done]***
  you can just retrieve it from the database every time you need it, a better way is to keep it in the session at the same way the user data (like address, telephone)in the class `User` is kept
- **A way to change the user preference *[40 % done]***
  some check box in the user settings page, it's also preferable (UX wise) that the user preference is shown in the header next to his name and can be edited directly from there
- **And finally, displaying products based on that preference *[100 % done :D]***
  you will need to change some code in the controller of the category page, best seller module, latest products .... (any module that involves displaying products)

  - **Simple, naive and ugly solution:**
    you will notice that there is a code segment that copies products data to the view data, it looks like 
    `$data['products'][] = array(` in OC 2.X and `$this->data['products'][] = array(` for versions prior to OC 2, a simple if condition here will be enough, just check for the user preference and decide accordingly whether to copy the product to the view data or not
  - **Better solution:**
     filter products based on the user preference from the very beginning in the model functions, add an extra optional parameter to all model functions that retrieves products (don't forget those functions that retrieves products count) that indicates the user preference, check inside model functions if the parameter is set then do you work in the query